# jquery multiple ajax call with parsejson

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have 3 ajax calls one after the other, which calls their respective web services. These web services return parseJSON objects. In all 3 ajax call I populate dropdown list with these parseJSON object value. But it populates only 1st and 3rd list and not 2nd one. So what is the issue?

My code is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function () {

     //For test
     $ConUrl = 'http://mydomain.com/WebService.asmx/FetchCountry?callback=parseJSON?';
     $StateUrl = 'http://mydomain.com/WebService.asmx/FetchState?callback=parseJSON?';
     $CityUrl = 'http://mydomain.com/WebService.asmx/FetchCity?callback=parseJSON?';

     populateCountries();

 });  // ready end


     function populateCountries() {

         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: $ConUrl,
             processData: true,
             data: {},
             dataType: "jsonp",
             jsonpCallback: 'parseJSON',
             success: function (data) {
                 var html = '<option value="0">All Regions</option>';
                 var len = data.length;
                 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                     html += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('select#ddlCountry').append(html);
                 populateStates();

             },
             error: function (data) { }
         });


     }

     function populateStates() {

         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: $StateUrl,
             processData: true,
             data: {},
             dataType: "jsonp",
             jsonpCallback: 'parseJSON',
             success: function (data1) {
                 var html1 = '<option value="0">All States</option>';
                 var len1 = data1.length;
                 for (var j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
                     html1 += '<option value="' + data1[j] + '">' + data1[j] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('select#ddlState').append(html1);
                 populateCities();

             },
             error: function (data1) { }
         });


     }

     function populateCities() {

         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: $CityUrl,
             processData: true,
             data: {},
             dataType: "jsonp",
             jsonpCallback: 'parseJSON',
             success: function (data2) {
                 var html2 = '<option value="0">All Cities</option>';
                 var len2 = data2.length;
                 for (var k = 0; k < len2; k++) {
                     html2 += '<option value="' + data2[k] + '">' + data2[k] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('select#ddlCity').append(html2);

             },
             error: function (data2) { }
         });
     }
</script>
```

Comment: anyone who can help in this?

Answer (score 0):

issue Solved ... the issue was not in jquery.... it was in  tag....

I was writing as follows....

```
<select id="ddlCountry" class="searchbox roundedcornerstyle" style="width:160px;" />
<select id="ddlState" class="searchbox roundedcornerstyle" style="width:160px;" />
<select id="ddlCity" class="searchbox roundedcornerstyle" style="width:160px;" />
```

After changing above lines as below, it git solved...

```
<select id="ddlCountry" class="searchbox roundedcornerstyle" style="width:160px;"></select>
<select id="ddlState" class="searchbox roundedcornerstyle" style="width:160px;"></select>
<select id="ddlCity" class="searchbox roundedcornerstyle" style="width:160px;"></select>
```

It really took too much time to find this.. but at last it solved...